# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_XBarChart

Tags: ios, charts, xcode10.2

I use the [Daniel Gindi Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library in my project. It works fine when I run in in the Simulator, but when I run it on a real device I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you check that it has been added to the Embedded Binaries section in the target settings?

Comment: @BojanDimovski, I added now in target settings, Those 3 errors gone, I am getting No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7). THIS ERROR. Help me on this!

Comment: Check for universal library, as this framework contains only simulator archs.